# How to load bulk data to the client side through javascript api call

Tags: javascript, php, api, iteration

I have around 10000+ records in my website.I applied pagination to list them.But other than listing there is a map view to pin the listings.then user can search in the map.For that i want the full data in the client side as a json array.I done this like

```
function doInBackground(){
       $.get('car/get-map-data',
          {
           'params':'$params'
           'page':page
      },
      function(data){
        if(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
        }
      }); 
    }
```

This is my api call.And my controller api is

```
public function actionGetMapData($params){
        $searchModel=new CarSearch();
        $dataProvider=$searchModel->search($params);
        $models=$dataProvider->getModels();
        $mapData=array();
        foreach ($models as $key => $model) {
            array_push($mapData, $model->title);
        }
         return json_encode($mapData);
     }
```

I have a page size of 10 in the search

```
$query = Car::find();
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10,
            ],
        ]);
```

I am iterating the above javascript function to get all data page by page to the client side.But sometimes it getting very slow.How can i overcome this.i want to add the datas to my map view.hence the map view also getting slower.**How to load 10000+ listing to client fastly**

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you only retrieve 10 items with each API call. If you have 10,000 items, it means that you are making 1000 API calls to retrieve all items. This will definitely not be performing well. You could try to load all 10,000 items in one go and then only do pagination on the client-side.

That said, it may not be "fast" to retrieve 10,000+ items from your API. It will depend on how fast your API can retrieve those items and what each item looks like. If they are simple objects, this could work but if they are objects with many properties, the size of the response will likely be a bottleneck.

In that case, you will need to perform the search on the API in order for it be as fast as possible.